# MSIX packaged WPF app that prevent multiple instances of windows?

Tags: c#, wpf, msix

I developed a WPF application with .NET 5.0, and wrap it with a MSIX Windows Application Packaging Project.

The question is that how can I prevent opening multiple instances of the application?

My requirement is: each time when the users go to Windows Start menu and open the application, the existing application window should become active instead of opening a new application window.

Comment: So you only want to be able to run a single instance of your app?

Comment: Have you considered using a mutex?

Answer (score 0):

You could define a custom `Main` method that uses a `Mutex` to ensure that only one instance of your app is created:

```
class Program
{
    const string AppUniqueGuid = "FB3808FB-57B7-4E38-B437-0F4E6EC3E4E2";

    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (Mutex mutex = new Mutex(false, AppUniqueGuid))
        {
            if (mutex.WaitOne(0, false))
            {
                App application = new App();
                application.InitializeComponent();
                application.Run();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Select `Program` as the "Startup object" under Project->Properties of the WPF application project in Visual Studio.